# Conditional expectation: pulling out independent r.v. as constant?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $Z_1,Z_1',\cdots,Z_n,Z_n'$ are all iid random variables and $f$ is a measurable function. Consier the following random variable

$$I\left(f(Z_1,\cdots,Z_n) > t\right) I \left(f(Z_1',\cdots,Z_n')\le \frac{t}{2} \right)$$

where $I$ is indicator function.

Now, if we "take expected value over $Z_1',\cdots,Z_n'$, why would we get

$$I\left(f\left(Z_1,\cdots,Z_n\right)>t \right) \mathbb{P}\left\{ f\left(Z_1',\cdots,Z_n'\right) \le \frac{t}{2} \mid Z_1',\cdots,Z_n
\right\}\,?$$

Accoring to the [lecture video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WalRR9lcZcc&t=1165s) here (around 28:40), "since we are taking expectation value with respect to $Z_1',\cdots,Z_n'$, and these two terms are independent, the first terms is just a constant". But this does not make any sense to me. If we are conditioning on $Z_1',\cdots,Z_n
'$, shouldn't $Z_1',\cdots,Z_n'$ be "constant" and $Z_1,\cdots,Z_n$ be random?

More formally, I considered

$$\mathbb{E}\left[I\left(f(Z_1,\cdots,Z_n) > t\right) I \left(f(Z_1',\cdots,Z_n')\le \frac{t}{2} \right) \mid \sigma\left( Z_1',\cdots,Z_n'\right)\right]$$

Since the second term is $\sigma\left(Z_1',\cdots,Z_n'\right)$-measurable, I can pull that one out, but this gives me exactly the opposite expression. What is going on?

**Update:** Here is the note I'm reading

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\mathbb{E}(X Y \, \mid \, \sigma(Y)) = \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y \, \mid \, \sigma(Y)) = \mathbb{E}(X) Y$.  In your case, it is true that the $Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}$ term "pulls out as a constant," but that constant should be $\mathbb{E}(I(f(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{m}) > t)$, not $I(f(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{m}) > t)$.  In other words, your result should be 
$$\mathbb{E} \left(I(f(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}) > t) I(f(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}') \leq \frac{t}{2}) \, \mid \, Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}'\right) = \mathbb{E}(I(f(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}) > t)) \mathbb{E}\left(I(f(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}') \leq \frac{t}{2} \, \mid \, Z_{1}', \dots, Z_{n}'\right) = \mathbb{P}(f(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}) > t)I \left(f(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}') \leq \frac{t}{2}\right)$$

EDIT:  I just watched the video.  I don't think the lecturer is conditioning on $Z_{1}',Z_{2}',\dots,Z_{n}'$.  Instead, he's integrating over those variables!  Notice how he uses this symbol $\mathbb{P}'$.  This is the law of $Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}'$.  It's not totally obvious what he's doing, but he seems to be gearing his talk towards applied math folks (or students who know probability "intuitively") and I agree that from a purely measure theoretic point of view it's not entirely clear what he means.

Consider this, though: if $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then, on the probability space $(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}, \mu \otimes \nu)$, we have two canonical random variables $X$ and $Y$ given by $X(x,y) = x$ and $Y(x,y) = y$.  These are independent since we're working with a product measure.  If $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are any Borel functions, then when I study the quantity $f(X) g(Y)$ then (from an analysis point of view) it's clear that I can integrate over $y$ if I like and thereby obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(y) \, \nu(dy) = f(x) \mathbb{E}(g(Y)).$$
I think this is what your lecturer was doing with $\mathbb{P}'$, except instead of working with two independent RV $X$ and $Y$ he was working with two independent "random vectors" $(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n})$ and $(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')$.  For him, $\mathbb{P}'$ is what in my sketch I called $\nu$.

Now the question is how do we formalize what was done in that lecture?  Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ denote the probability space the lecturer is (implicitly) working in.  Then the random vector $(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n},Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')$ has a "law" which I will denote by $\mathbb{P}_{Z}$.  This is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.  Recall that $\mathbb{P}_{Z}$ is defined (implicitly) by $$\mathbb{P}_{Z}(A_{1} \times \dots \times  A_{n} \times A_{1}' \times \dots \times A_{n}' ) = \mathbb{P}\{Z_{1} \in A_{1}, \dots, Z_{n} \in A_{n}, Z_{1}' \in A_{1}', \dots, Z_{n}' \in A_{n}'\}.$$
Moreover, since $(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n})$ and $(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')$ are independent, $\mathbb{P}_{Z}$ is a product measure given by $\mathbb{P}_{Z} = \mathbb{P}_{Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}} \otimes \mathbb{P}_{Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}'}$, where $\mathbb{P}_{Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}'}$ are the respective laws of $(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n})$ and $(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')$.

Now if $f, g : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions (in your case, they were indicator functions), then the law of the random vector $(f(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}),g(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}'))$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ equals the law of the random vector $(f,g)$ on $(\mathbb{R}^{2d},\mathscr{B}_{R^{2n}},\mathbb{P}_{Z})$, where by $(f,g)$ I mean the random vector $(f,g) : \mathbb{R}^{2d} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by $$(f,g)(z_{1},\dots,z_{n},z_{1}',\dots,z_{n}')= (f(z_{1},\dots,z_{n}),g(z_{1}',z_{2}',\dots,z_{n}')).$$
Now that we're working on $(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}},\mathbb{P}_{Z})$, it's clear what it means to "average over the last $n$ variables."  In particular, this is 
$$f(z_{1},\dots,z_{n}) \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} g(z_{1}',\dots,z_{n}') \, \mathbb{P}_{Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}'}(dz_{1}',\dots,dz_{n}').$$

Finally, we should ask: what does this mean probabilistically?  (Or what's a "coordinate-free" interpretation?)  The answer (somewhat unintuitively for me) is clearly the conditional expectation with respect to $\sigma(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n})$, *not* $\sigma(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')$.  Indeed, by independence, 
$$\mathbb{E}(f(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}) g(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}') \, \mid \, \sigma(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n})) = f(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}) \mathbb{E}(g(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}'))$$
and, by a change of measure,
$$\mathbb{E}(g(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} g(z_{1}',\dots,z_{n}') \, \mathbb{P}_{Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}'}(dz_{1}',\dots,dz_{n}').$$

My conclusion is his intuitive "integrating over $(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')$" somewhat unintuitively corresponds to conditioning on $\sigma(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n})$.  We should bear in mind the fact that these two ideas are equivalent is a consequence of the fact that $(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n})$ and $(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')$ are independent.  I don't have a good explanation for why conditioning on $\sigma(Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n})$ corresponds to averaging over the $(Z_{1}',\dots,Z_{n}')$ variables, though I wish I did.

Comment: Would you please read my update? What you are getting here (and what I got by myself earlier) contradicts the note I'm reading.

Comment: OK, I read the video.  I'm thinking about it.  What he's doing is integrating over $Z_{1}',Z_{2}',\dots,Z_{n}'$, not conditioning on those variables.  In fact, I think this is equivalent to conditioning on $Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}$, which is counterintuitive.  Anyway, I'll edit my answer with my thoughts.

Comment: Wow, seems like it's more complicated than I first thought because all the textbooks and notes I found are very handwaving on this part, strangely... I need to take some time reading it.

Comment: Two quick questions. First, what do we mean by integrating over random variables? I only know integration over probability measure (something like $\int_\Omega  X(\omega) \,dP$. Second, what is "law of some random variable"?

Comment: Much of what I wrote is intuitive or assumes you're familiar with concepts like the law of a random variable.  If you're not, then it may be better just to note that what he is doing is formally the same as conditioning on $Z_{1},\dots,Z_{n}$ (as you seemed to notice in your original post when you wrote "just the opposite expression").

Comment: By the way, these introductory notes on measure-theoretic probability are very good: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/probnotes.pdf  The only difficulty is what he calls the "distribution" of a random variable is what I have called the "law."

Comment: I guess I just needed some clarification. When you say "integrate over $y$" and wrote $\int v(dy)$, are we integrating wrt to measure defined on $\mathhbb{R}$ induced by random variable $Y$?

Comment: Also can I find "change of measure" in that notes? I've been teaching myself mainly using Kai Lai Chung and couldn't find things like "change of measure theorem" in the book.

Comment: What I call "change of measure" others call "change of variables": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula